# read Text File and Make Changes c#

Tags: c#

i want to read a text file that Contains

```
<CustomerName>@CoustomerName</CoustomerName>
<CustomerAddress>@CustomerAddress</CustomerAddress>
<CustomerMobileNo>@CustomerMobileNo</CustomerMobileNo>
<Payment>@Payment</Payment>
```

Replace this @CoustomerName with Coustomer Name Passes During Run Time

Till then i use this

```
string readfile = File.ReadAllText(path);
Regex.Replace(readfile , "@CoustomerName ", objProposar.FirstName);
```

This works But i need to make changes in Coustomer address, mobile no etc
    How can i do this

Comment: It looks that you have an *XML*, if it's your case why not use, say, `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

Why regex, a simple `String.Replace` will do the job:

```
string oldText = File.ReadAllText(path);
string newText = oldText.Replace("@CoustomerName", objProposar.FirstName);
// other ...
File.WriteAllText(path, newText);
```

Comment: @MukulKhatter: interesting, what happened instead?

Comment: how can i remove a string from text file say <CustomerMobileNo>@CustomerMobileNo</CustomerMobileNo>

Comment: @MukulKhatter: you have to create the string that you want to save, then write all text as shown above. You have multiple options, for example: `newText=newText.Replace("<CustomerMobileNo>@CustomerMobileNo</CustomerMobileNo>", "");`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is XML - use XML way of doing it, like XDocument, otherwise `string.Replace` is a better option:

```
string readfile = File.ReadAllText(path);
readfile = readfile.Replace("@CoustomerName", objProposar.FirstName);
```